# Read .mat files from Unix shell

Tags: matlab, shell, unix, mat

Is there a way to read .mat files from the UNIX command line shell?

Such as cat `mymat.mat` ?

I am aware of the possibilities to load it in MATLAB or python, but these are not available for me atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**GNU Octave** may be an option as it can be freely installed without cost.

Say you ran a session something like this and created two arrays, A and B:

```
octave:1> A = [ 1:3; 4:6; 7:9 ];
octave:2> B = [ 11:13; 14:16; 17:19 ];
octave:3> save -7 myfile.mat A B
```

Then, in the shell, outside of Octave, you could do this to see the names of the variables in the file:

```
$ octave-cli <<< "who -file myfile.mat"
```

**Sample Output**

```
Variables in the file myfile.mat:

A  B
```

And then this to dump the variables:

```
 $ octave-cli <<< "load myfile.mat;A"
```

**Sample Output**

```
A =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9
```

And:

```
$ octave-cli <<< "load myfile.mat;B"
```

**Sample Output**

```
B =

   11   12   13
   14   15   16
   17   18   19
```

Answer (score 0):

No. .mat-files are saved in a binary format. You will not be able to interpret their content from the UNIX shell.

Comment: The MAT file format [is not proprietary](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf). Newer versions use an HDF5 based format, which is also not proprietary.

Comment: I was not aware that the internal format of .mat-files is officially documented. Good to know.
However, it is still not possible to directly read .mat-files from the Unix shell by using a simple command (without additional software installed).